# react native android files and media permissions not showing in settings

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, react-native-permissions

`Android is not showing permissions in settings also  I have used react-native-permissions for this`

React-native-permissions : version =>

```
"^3.8.3"
```

Android Version => "13"

Model Name => Samsung A53s and Redmi Power 10

I have use this also in android manifest file:

"

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

"

but in settings am not able to see permissions for files and media.